# AD search filter syntax for "all users in a specified OU DN path"

Tags: active-directory, ldap

What is the search filter syntax for "all users under the given OU DN"? Looking at the docs here (https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5392.active-directory-ldap-syntax-filters.aspx) did not seem to answer this question (though am totally new to AD, so may be here in another wording).

Use case is that I have an AD path "OU=Users,OU=HortonworksUsers,DC=ucera,DC=local" under which there are several `person` entries (ie. thier attribute objectClass OID is "top;person;organizationalPerson;user"). I would like to add them to a search filter (for Apache Ranger [AD usersync](https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.0.1/configuring-ranger-authe-with-unix-ldap-ad/content/ranger_ad_integration_ranger_usersync.html)), but have only seen examples of filtering for a specified group, ie. "memberOf=".

Can anyone with more AD experience let me know the right way to filter for users under some arbitrary OU DN?

Comment: For my particular use case, I made use of the fact that Apache ranger AD usersync configs *can take multiple search bases* (using the `;` separator). So my search base ended up looking like `dc=myorg,dc=local;ou=Users,ou=HortonworksUsers,dc=myorg,dc=local` (then sorted the rest out via search filter configs).

Comment: Also, for my use case, could have also put all desired users into an `group` under the OU and added that group as a user search filter in Ranger configs in Ambari (ie. as filter string `memberOf=< DN path of the created group >`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To grab all users under the given OU, you need to set the following search parameters :

- base dn : `OU=Users,OU=HortonworksUsers,DC=ucera,DC=local`
- scope : `subtree` or `sub` (which is the default for most ldap client)
- filter : `(|(objectClass=person)(objectClass=user))`

Translated into ldapsearch options, you got something like :

```
ldapsearch -H ldap://<host>:<port> -D <bind_dn> -W -b OU=Users,OU=HortonworksUsers,DC=ucera,DC=local -s sub (|(objectClass=person)(objectClass=user))
```

Comment: This is correct. To more specifically answer the question: the *only* way to limit a search to an OU is to set the "base DN", or sometimes called "search root". There is no way to do this in the search filter alone.